# Invalid Post Data - Magento Connect

Tags: magento-connect

When I press on proceed  I got this error on Magento Connect :

Invalid Post Data

- How can I fix it ?
- Directory Permission ?

Answer (score 4):

The error appears when you try to send the form through _GET (or to much data send through POST). This code can be found in `downloader/Maged/Controller.php`: (`connectPreparePackagePostAction` and `connectInstallPackagePostAction` methods)

```
if (!$_POST) {
    echo "INVALID POST DATA";
    return;
}
```

Check what the `$_POST` variable looks like. Also check if you are not over the `post_max_size` limit with what you send.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to recent change in my `.htaccess`.

Thanks to this website (http://www.ecommerce-northern-ireland.co.uk/magento/upgrading-magento-via-magento-connect/) I now switch between 2 `.htaccess` files (optimized and normal) and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

it might also be a badly worded error message. they use the same error message if you have an invalid form key.  log back into the admin and then click the magento connect manager